# Row in table is getting locked after modifying a certain cell in it in oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql

I have the following code in an oracle procedure, which returns a cursor (`r_cursor`) as an `OUT` parameter

```
SELECT userid
      INTO v_userid
      FROM users u
     WHERE lower(u.email) = lower(p_email)
       AND lower(u.token) = lower(p_IV);

UPDATE users u
   SET u.token = NULL,
       u.lastlogin = sysdate()
 WHERE u.userid = v_userid;

  OPEN r_cursor FOR
    SELECT u.firstname,
           u.lastname
      FROM users u
     WHERE u.userid = v_userid;
```

When calling the procedure from oracle everything works completely fine.

But when calling the procedure from a .Net application, the error `ORA-24338: statement handle not executed` is raised.

After a lot of testing, I find out that if I remove one of the lines `lower(u.token) = lower(p_IV)` from the `SELECT` statement or `u.token = NULL,` from the `UPDATE` statement, the cursor is returned to the .Net application without any error.

Comment: Does the error occur when you call the stored procedure or when you use the cursor returned from the stored procedure? The former would indicate that either the OPEN statement has never been executed or the parameters defined in .NET got mixed up. The latter would indicate that you fetched from the cursor after you have reached the end of it, possibly because the cursor didn't return any row at all.

Comment: the error is happening when filling the dataset with the cursor returned.
oCon.Open();
oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
oDA.Fill(dsCustomer);
oDA.Dispose();
and as for the data, for sure the data is returned since the oracle procedure itself is working fine and returning good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORA-24338` is usually raised when you try to fetch a cursor that has not been opened yet.

This could be raised for example if your procedure raised an exception before the OPEN statement. Afterwards when you try to fetch from the cursor oracle would raise the `ORA-24338` since the cursor has never been opened.

Do you have an `EXCEPTION` block (with a `WHEN OTHERS` for example) in your PL/SQL, or do you catch SQL exception in `.net`?

Comment: exception handling is done .net side. the strange part is that the same parameters are tested oracle side and the resulted cursor is 100% correct.